# How to keep a bash script running when "set +e" is not enough?

Tags: bash, error-handling

I am calling a command written in C++ from a bash script (on Ubuntu 10.10). The command throws an exception and terminates, and the script is aborted.

Even with "set +e" or "command || true", the script will not continue.

How can I force the script to continue?

Comment: Please show your script, and a small C++ program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: what about `while : do done` or redirect stderr to /dev/null like so: `command 2> /dev/null`? ALSO POST YOUR SCRIPT!

Answer (score 4):

The shell script can trap any signal except 9 (KILL), with the "trap" command.  The special signal name "ERR" means any non-zero error status.

```
trap 'error=1' ERR
while true; do
  run-external-program
  code="$?"
  if [[ -n "$error" ]]; then
    echo "Caught an error! Status = $code"
    error=  # reset the error
  elif [[ "$code" != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Program exited with non-zero code: $code"
  fi
done
```

You can also tell the shell to ignore errors with an empty command:

```
   trap '' ERR
```

Comment: You may need to use `set -E` (errtrace) in order for this to work consistently. Typically subcommands don't inherit error traps